# Python - Search a list item that contains a string (match case)

Tags: python, regex, list

I need to search if any item of a list contains a specific string. At the moment I use this code:

```
mylist = ['Hometown City Heights', 'Height 6'', 'First name Mike']   
item = [s for s in mylist if "First name" in s]
print item[0]
>> First name Mike
```

The problem is that if I try so search `Height` I got this:

```
mylist = ['Hometown City Heights', 'Height 6'', 'First name Mike']   
item = [s for s in mylist if "Height" in s]
print item[0]
>> Hometown City Heights
```

I need to match only `Height` included in `Height 6'` element, so that item[0] will be the one that I need. What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your items and then check :

```
item = [s for s in mylist if "Height" in s.split()]
```

Demo :

```
>>> mylist = ['Hometown City Heights', "Height 6'"]
>>> [s for s in mylist if "Height" in s.split()]
["Height 6'"]
>>>
```

As a more general way you can use regex to search for your pattern :

```
import re
[s for s in mylist if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(pattern),s)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> pattern='First name'
>>> [s for s in mylist if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(pattern),s)]
['First name Mike']
```

Comment: Wow it works but I can't understand why! If I split `Hometown City Heights` and search inside for `Height`, why it doesn't match the `Heights` element?

Comment: @Hyperion glad of that, because `Height` is inside `Hometown City Heights'` but not `['Hometown', 'City', 'Heights']
`

Comment: Ok thanks but I've got a little problem there. This solution unfortunately doesn't works in every case, because I've got also field that are like `First name Mike` and I need to search the whole `First name` string, which won't work if I use split before

Comment: @Hyperion Yeah i wont works in that case pls add your example to questions, i'll update the answer.